# Kentico v9 Collapsible Panel header class issue

Tags: kentico

I've noticed when I add a Header CSS class in the web part properties, this value is added to the span and it's parent div for the header. Is this intentional? and what's the easiest way to 'fix' this. Ideally i think the class should only be applied to the wrapper tag on the header copy.

Comment: Good question Mark, I can replicate this in v8.2.32 so its not just a v9 issue. To be honest I've haven't used the Collapsible Panel webpart before, but for most webparts I tend to use the HTML Envelope Content Before and Content After properties to add wrappers with my own CSS Classes.

Comment: my APSX template has this webzone in a class with an ID. I'm trying to add an open/close icon for the panel. It may be easier to switch it out to something else. I need to implement a different accordion webpart, which should give me the control i need. In theory.

Comment: You might open up that webpart and see how that property is being used in the code behind.  Could be a pretty simple fix to apply it to the correct control in the code infront.

Comment: @MarkHandy You can always setup css class in web part container markup. However using of web part containers is not the best practice as those are extra hit for performance. I'd recommend using of content before/after - they are not as much user friendly, as containers, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspecting the HTML as you mentioned both the Div and the Span have your Header Class and you can tell by the generated IDs that Kentico have used asp:Panel and asp:Label controls.

Also it's worth noting that if you omit the Collapsed and Expanded text there is no Span.

I suspect that Kentico have made a concious decision to set the CssClass property on both Controls so that your class applies directly to the text in the Span. However this could have a negative side affect of applying your class to both Elements with CSS properties such as Padding and Margins.

The 'fix' for now would be to handle this in your CSS. Eg.

```
Div.yourClass { padding: 5px; background-color: #eee;}

Span.yourClass { color: #333;}
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, your fix is what I've been working with as i'm using :after to add an open/close icon. I noticed this as I was creating some custom JS to manipulate that icon on click.

Cheers!